# Searching multiple keys in text-box using coma seperator in between

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and i like to search multiple primary keys separated by comas and display the respective rows  in  the next page .  For example i have a table with 5 rows and the primary keys are like 1,2,3,4,5. Now in my search text-box if I type 1,2,3 it should display the first 3 columns in the next page.
I am a beginner to php , so i don't now whether it is possible .I have done the search for a single key and it is working fine.

Comment: providing an example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your textbox contains a string with comma separated values?

If so, you should be fine using the IN word like the previous answer, but comming from a PHP form:

LEAVING SECURITY AS AN OBVIOUS @TODO

```
$keys = $_POST['keys'];

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (' . $keys . ')';
$result = $whatever_object_you_using_for_database->query($query);
```

Would be great if you could uptade your question with the code you've tried, even the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

use IN:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id IN (1,2,4,6,88);
```